# How can I make an app linked against GLIBCXX_3.4.26 run on Raspbian Buster, which only offers 3.4.25?

Tags: c++, cross-compilation

I'm now trying to compile C++ apps for my Raspi 3B by using `crosstool-ng` on my OpenSuSE-based host machine. The toolchain now works fine, but when trying to run the app on the Raspi, I always get this error message:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ ./autoradio
./autoradio: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./autoradio)
```

In fact, support ends with version 3.4.25:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ strings /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
# previous versions omitted
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
```

The C++ standard library, which comes with the crosscompiler, is version 3.4.27 (!), though:

```
─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  strings /home/jacek/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
# previous versions omitted
GLIBCXX_3.4.27

╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v                                     127 ↵
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/jacek/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/libexec/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /opt/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/src/gcc/configure --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/jacek/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/jacek/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-float=soft --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.24.0.103_75d7525' --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libmpx --with-gmp=/opt/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-mpfr=/opt/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-mpc=/opt/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-isl=/opt/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --enable-lto --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-gold --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/jacek/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-long-long
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.103_75d7525)
```

According to `apt`, the library I've got on my raspi is the last one available with Raspbian Buster.

So, how do I upgrade the C++ stdlib on my Raspi to (at least) 3.4.26? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving some input from outside this forum, I found out that the default C++ compiler version of `x-tools` (9.2.0) is simply too new for Raspbian Buster, and downgrading to 8.3.0 in `ct-ng menuconfig` (see the screenshot below) resolved my issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Would you please detail the inputs you got outside this forum? I am running into the exact same problem of `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found with latest crosstool-ng.1.24 compiled toolchain binaries && `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found even though ct-ng menuconfig shows gcc version as 8.3 and also the $ ct-bg build downloaded the gcc_8.3.0.tar.xz . My raspberry pi with DietPi buster distro shows GLIBCXX_3.4.25 max for libstdc++.so.6

Comment: Unfortunately this was a German-language forum where I re-posted my issue, but I can still give you its link: https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/51577-c-crosscompiler-fuer-raspi-3b-armv7l/?pageNo=1 This issue is the following: Buster (on the Pi) is simply too old to run binaries compiled with g++ 9.2 included in my x-tools. You have to resort to 8.3 and switch on the NEON FPU & SIMD.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That thread was useful. Before posting this I waited for  x-tools build with  armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf(gcc version=8.3, glib = 2.28) + webrtc build to be verified and its different but similar problem - 'GLIBC_2.29' not found after 5-6 hrs of builds. So far I have tried toolchains from armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/ armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabihf sample configs and everyone of them give the same runtime error - 'GLIBC_2.29' not found.  raspberry pi with DietPi buster distro shows GLIBC_2.28 max for libc.so.6

Comment: I have no idea where this - 'GLIBC_2.29' dependency is creeping in even though the glibc-2.28.tar.xz is the one built by ct-ng used. I suspect webrtc dependency on libraries outside the gcc-toolchain is bringing the 'GLIBC_2.29' dependency but I am not sure yet how to prove it or verify/isolate those dependencies.

Comment: As suspected, /webrtc/src/build/linux/debian-arm-systoor/ had  GLIBC_2.29 dependency (strings * | grep "" )   - BUT it was my bad - in my trashing around with sysroots and toolchains I guess I corrupted it. Repeating the whole fetch-sync procedure from scratch resolved eliminated the  'GLIBC_2.29' dependency. In short, your solution works with the addition of choosing glib = 2.28 in ct-ng menuconfig while building the arm toolchain.